# How to access file system in Ripple emulator launched via Visual Studio Cordova project?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, fileapi, ripple

I have seen some posts where we can provide the "--allow-file-access-from-files"  flag for chrome, but in my case Visual Studio will automatically open Chrome.I need to save file to file system using file select html 5 element or download from a service. I also want to read the files stored in the file system. I have the working code which works for google chrome sandbox file system, but for ripple it shows the "I has Cheeseburger" error.

Comment: Are you using any cordova plugins?

Comment: Yes. I am using cordova file plugin.

Comment: `Caution: Ripple doesn’t provide a complete simulation of Cordova APIs or native device capabilities (plugins).` Please see Caution of [this link](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ripple-simulator/). You can try it on real device or emulators.

Comment: Let me provide some more information. I want to read a file from emulator file system and upload it to a local server for debugging. If I run it on real device I am not able to hit the local server for debugging. This is the reason I want to use the emulator.